# My Drawing Finder

Tags: c#, wpf, sqlite

I developed this application for the company I work for. It became increasingly challenging to locate drawings within the myriad of folders, especially when searching for the most up-to-date versions.

I have another app that generates an index of files, boasting over 90 thousand entries. The index includes the name, format, path, and date of each file. The finder application reads this file, and when you input the part number of a drawing, it opens the desired format for you. I utilized SQLite to create the .db file for this purpose.

I'm seeking feedback on this code—wondering if there are any potential improvements or if there's already a more efficient program available for the same task.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.SQLite;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace Finder
{
    public enum ErrorType
    {
        InvalidPartNumber,
        FilesNotFound,
        FolderNotFound,
        FailedToOpenFile,
        FailedToOpenFolder,
        OpenFolder,
        OpenFile
    }

    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public ICommand ClearInputFieldsCommand { get; }
        private const int minimum = 8;
        private string sourceDir;
        private FileSystemWatcher watcher;
        private SQLiteConnection connection;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            ClearInputFieldsCommand = new RelayCommand(ClearInputFieldsButton);
            DataContext = this;

            string documentsPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
            string folderPath = Path.Combine(documentsPath, "FinderDatabase");
            Directory.CreateDirectory(folderPath);

            string sourceFileName = Path.GetFileName(@"");
            sourceDir = Path.Combine(folderPath, sourceFileName);

            string sourceFilePath = @"";

            if (File.Exists(sourceDir))
            {
                File.Delete(sourceDir);
            }

            File.Copy(sourceFilePath, sourceDir);

            string killFolder = @"";
            string killFile = "killkey.txt";

            watcher = new FileSystemWatcher(killFolder, killFile);
            watcher.Created += WatcherCreated;
            watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

            string killFilePath = Path.Combine(killFolder, killFile);
            if (File.Exists(killFilePath))
            {
                Close();
            }

            string connectionString = $"DataSource={sourceDir};Version=3;";
            connection = new SQLiteConnection(connectionString, true);
            connection.Open();
        }

        private void WatcherCreated(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Name == "killkey.txt")
            {
                Close();
            }
        }

        private void btnAbrirArquivo_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            string pesquisa = txtPesquisa.Text.Trim();
            if (!IsValid(pesquisa))
            {
                ShowPopup(ErrorType.InvalidPartNumber);
                return;
            }

            string[] extensoesSelecionadas = GetSelectedExtensions();
            List<ArquivoEncontrado> arquivosEncontrados = BuscarArquivos(pesquisa, extensoesSelecionadas);

            if (arquivosEncontrados.Count > 0)
            {
                ArquivoEncontrado arquivoParaAbrir = arquivosEncontrados.OrderByDescending(arquivo => File.GetLastWriteTime(arquivo.Path)).First();
                OpenFile(arquivoParaAbrir.Path);
            }
            else
            {
                ShowPopup(ErrorType.FilesNotFound);
            }
        }

        private bool IsValid(string query)
        {
            if (query.Length < minimum)
            {
                return false;
            }

            foreach (char c in query)
            {
                if (!char.IsDigit(c) && c != '-')
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }

            string[] parts = query.Split('-');
            foreach (string part in parts)
            {
                if (!int.TryParse(part, out _))
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return true;
        }

        private void btnAbrirPasta_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            string pesquisa = txtPesquisa.Text.Trim();
            if (!IsValid(pesquisa))
            {
                ShowPopup(ErrorType.InvalidPartNumber);
                return;
            }

            string[] extensoesSelecionadas = GetSelectedExtensions();
            List<ArquivoEncontrado> arquivoEncontrados = BuscarArquivos(pesquisa, extensoesSelecionadas);

            if (arquivoEncontrados.Count > 0)
            {
                string pastaParaAbrir = Path.GetDirectoryName(arquivoEncontrados[0].Path);
                OpenFolder(pastaParaAbrir);
            }
            else
            {
                ShowPopup(ErrorType.FolderNotFound);
            }
        }

        private string[] GetSelectedExtensions()
        {
            List<string> selectedExtensions = new List<string>();

            if (chkPdf.IsChecked == true)
                selectedExtensions.Add(".pdf");
            if (chkStp.IsChecked == true)
                selectedExtensions.Add(".stp");
            if (chkDwg.IsChecked == true)
                selectedExtensions.Add(".dwg");
            if (chkJt.IsChecked == true)
                selectedExtensions.Add(".jt");

            return selectedExtensions.ToArray();
        }

        private List<ArquivoEncontrado> BuscarArquivos(string pesquisa, string[] extensoesSelecionadas)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(pesquisa))
                return new List<ArquivoEncontrado>();

            List<ArquivoEncontrado> arquivosEncontrados = new List<ArquivoEncontrado>();

            string connectionString = $"Data Source={sourceDir};Version=3;";
            using (SQLiteConnection connection = new SQLiteConnection(connectionString, true))
            {
                connection.Open();
                string query = "SELECT Name, Extension, Path FROM Files WHERE Name LIKE @pesquisa AND Extension IN ({0})";
                string extensionsPlaceholder = string.Join(",", extensoesSelecionadas.Select(e => $"'{e}'"));
                query = string.Format(query, extensionsPlaceholder);

                using (SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(query, connection))
                {
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pesquisa", $"%{pesquisa}%");

                    using (SQLiteDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            string nomeArquivo = reader.GetString(0);
                            string extensaoArquivo = reader.GetString(1);
                            string caminhoArquivo = reader.GetString(2);

                            arquivosEncontrados.Add(new ArquivoEncontrado
                            {
                                Name = nomeArquivo,
                                Extension = extensaoArquivo,
                                Path = caminhoArquivo,
                            });

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return arquivosEncontrados;
        }

        private void OpenFile(string filePath)
        {
            try
            {
                using (Process process = new Process())
                {
                    process.StartInfo.FileName = filePath;
                    process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
                    process.Start();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ShowPopup(ErrorType.FailedToOpenFile, ex);
            }
        }

        private void OpenFolder(string folderPath)
        {
            try
            {
                using (Process process = new Process())
                {
                    process.StartInfo.FileName = "explorer.exe";
                    process.StartInfo.Arguments = $"/select, \"{SelectFile(folderPath)}\"";
                    process.Start();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ShowPopup(ErrorType.FailedToOpenFolder, ex);
            }
        }

        private string SelectFile(string folderPath)
        {
            string pesquisa = txtPesquisa.Text.Trim();
            string[] extensoesSelecionadas = GetSelectedExtensions();
            List<ArquivoEncontrado> arquivoEncontrados = BuscarArquivos(pesquisa, extensoesSelecionadas);

            if (arquivoEncontrados.Count > 0)
            {
                if (Path.GetDirectoryName(arquivoEncontrados[0].Path) == folderPath)
                {
                    return arquivoEncontrados[0].Path;
                }
            }
            return folderPath;
        }

        private void ShowPopup(ErrorType errorType, Exception exception = null)
        {
            string errorMessage = GetErrorMessage(errorType);
            string exceptionMessage = exception?.Message;

            PopupErro popup = new PopupErro(errorMessage + " " + exceptionMessage);
            popup.Owner = this;
            popup.ShowDialog();
        }

        private string GetErrorMessage(ErrorType errorType)
        {
            switch (errorType)
            {
                case ErrorType.InvalidPartNumber:
                    return "Part number inválido.";
                case ErrorType.FilesNotFound:
                    return "Arquivo não encontrado.";
                case ErrorType.FolderNotFound:
                    return "Pasta não encontrada.";
                case ErrorType.FailedToOpenFile:
                    return "Erro ao abrir o arquivo.";
                case ErrorType.FailedToOpenFolder:
                    return "Erro ao abrir pasta.";
                default:
                    return string.Empty;
            }
        }

        private void ClearInputFieldsButton()
        {
            txtPesquisa.Text = string.Empty;
        }

        public class RelayCommand : ICommand
        {
            private readonly Action _execute;
            public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

            public RelayCommand(Action execute)
            {
                _execute = execute;
            }

            public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
            {
                return true;
            }

            public void Execute(object parameter)
            {
                _execute();
            }
        }
    }

    public class ArquivoEncontrado
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Extension { get; set; }
        public string Path { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you need from the community? Are you looking for an optimisation of your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## informative identifier

```
namespace Finder
```

Maybe a bit on the vague side?
Consider `DrawingFinder` or even `FileFinder`.

```
        private const int minimum = 8;
```

That's just super vague, it's unhelpful.
Definitely rename to `minimumQueryLength`.
Contrast it with some of your other
name choices which were excellent, such as `sourceDir`.

We don't appear to be using ALL_CAPS here
for manifest constants. I assume that's what
your project wants, that's fine.

```
                case ErrorType.FilesNotFound:
                    return "Arquivo não encontrado.";
```

It appears this enum should be singular: `FileNotFound`

---

## odd idiom

It's unclear why you habitually write the empty string as `@""`,
since there's no `\` backwhack (or indeed *any*) characters
where we need to worry about escaping.

If you're trying to adhere to some coding standard
that requires this, mention it in comments near the top,
or in the project's ReadMe.md, or in Code Review context prose
near top of posting.

Prefer to write something informative like ELIDED if the
source code you posted is deliberately censoring sensitive
information which appeared in the original source code.
Consider putting such strings in an `.ini` config file
rather than using embedded hard-code values.

---

## pick a language

Your "button open file click" callback
inexplicably switches to Portuguese identifiers.
Similarly down in `btnAbrirPasta_Click`,
which should share code via a helper function
rather than being copy-pasta code.
Also `BuscarArquivos` and `ArquivoEncontrado`.

Your project should have a ReadMe that describes
which linter / prettyprinter we use,
and what natural language we use for identifiers.
During code review, revise proposed edits
which don't conform to the project's policy.

---

## comments

I found `IsValid` trickier to understand than necessary.
At first blush it appears to be looking for integers.
Eventually it becomes clear that the final loop
is really looking for empty strings such as these invalid part numbers:

- `-123-456`
- `123--456`
- `123-456-`

If you retain the code as written,
tack on a comment which explains
the **why** behind that final loop.

Or have the code explicitly test for empty strings,
rather than relying on integer parse of empty string to fail.
(Or was there some other requirement here,
like components shall be less than four billion? Then say it!)

---

## concise boolean expressions

In `GetSelectedExtensions`
prefer `if (chkPdf.IsChecked)`,
without the `== True`.

---

## frequent re-open of DB

In `BuscarArquivos`,
kudos on properly using bind variables
in the query, so as to evade Little Bobby Tables.

Perhaps we close and re-open the database
more often than is desirable, discarding
cached rows and parsed schemas more often
than necessary.
Consider opening the DB just once,
either at app startup or upon initial query.

Your SELECT query should have an ORDER BY clause,
since it's the **first** result that will be opened.
Also we like to see a stable order for reproducible
results, though it appears the way you've structured
your code it would be difficult to bolt on automated integration or
[unit tests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/testing/unit-testing-best-practices).

---

## disabled index

I assume you want to *quickly* retrieve one matching part number
from `10**5` entries.

The current SELECT uses leading `%` wildcard.
So even if there's an index on `Name`, it won't be used.
It's not like there's some full-text search feature
of the backend that's being used here.

Consider sticking with just a trailing `%` wildcard
if your use case allows it, since that plays nicely with indexes.

But suppose you *do* need it.
Without resorting to creation of full-text search indexes,
there's at least two ways to finesse this.

1. Issue an "easy" `1234-567%` prefix query which might return early, and if no results then fall back to a "tablescan" `%1234-567%` retry query.
2. Store a hundred million reversed part number strings in a `ReversedName` column, which is indexed. Let your suffix retry query exploit that index when it looks for `765-4321%`. If *that* fails, final fall back is still that original double-percent tablescan.

---

This codebase appears to achieve its design goals.
It would benefit from an automated test suite,
and reduced code duplication via extracting helpers.

I would not be willing to accept maintenance tasks on it.
I would be willing to delegate maintenance tasks to
colleagues who have a working knowledge of both
Portuguese and English.

Comment: I provided some explanations; [here is the link.](https://pastebin.com/7N8bU0gg)

Comment: I made all the updates you suggested and found your comments to be of great importance. Thank you once again.